# How to add an extra number on top of the each bar on barchart

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, visualization, seaborn, data-analysis

**According to the explanation why this question is different from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31749448/how-to-add-percentages-on-top-of-bars-in-seaborn)**
this link get the height from the diagram as far as I understood, but in my case I do not have this column `numpatients6month` in the diagram at all, I just have that on the data frame.

So I have a bar chart. It contains two bar for each `x-axis` in which each bar read from different data frame.

this is the code I am plotting the bar chart.

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rcParams['axes.prop_cycle'] = ("cycler('color', 'rg')")
dffinal['CI-noCI']='Cognitive Impairement'
nocidffinal['CI-noCI']='Non Cognitive Impairement'
res=pd.concat([dffinal,nocidffinal])

sns.barplot(x='6month',y='final-formula',data=res,hue='CI-noCI').set_title(fs)
plt.xticks(fontsize=8, rotation=45)
```

plt.show()

as you see there is `two data frame`. I plot `dffinal` with color `green` and `nocidffinal` with color `red`.

This is the result of plot:

[image]

**Some more explanation:** `dffinal` is based on `(6month, final-formula)` `nocidffinal` is also based on`(6month,final-formula)`.

this is my `nocidffinal` data frame:

```
          6month  final-formula  numPatients6month
137797.0       1       0.035934                974
267492.0       2       0.021705                645
269542.0       3       0.022107                769
271950.0       4       0.020000                650
276638.0       5       0.015588                834
187719.0       6       0.019461                668
218512.0       7       0.011407                789
199830.0       8       0.008863                677
269469.0       9       0.003807                788
293390.0      10       0.009669                724
254783.0      11       0.012195                738
300974.0      12       0.009695                722
```

and `dffinal`:

```
          6month  final-formula  numPatients6month
166047.0       1       0.077941                680
82972.0        2       0.057208                437
107227.0       3       0.057348                558
111330.0       4       0.048387                434
95591.0        5       0.033708                534
95809.0        6       0.036117                443
98662.0        7       0.035524                563
192668.0       8       0.029979                467
89460.0        9       0.009709                515
192585.0      10       0.021654                508
184325.0      11       0.017274                521
85068.0       12       0.010438                479
```

As you see there is column `numPatients6month` in this dataframeS which I would like to show on top of each bar.
I do `NOT` want to change the barchart and group it based on this column, rather I want to just show this number as extra information to the user on top of each bar.

thanks for your time :)

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest can you please unmarked as duplicate? I added explanations how it differs from your link!!!

Comment: I reopened. I think you should also add in how far [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43214978/seaborn-barplot-displaying-values) does not help.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest sure I will add even more info how they did not help me as I tried three different things I found in stack. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you get your `numPatients6month` columns in one iterable and in order they appear in chart then using the other [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31749448/how-to-add-percentages-on-top-of-bars-in-seaborn) answer (also in the docs [here](https://matplotlib.org/2.0.2/examples/api/barchart_demo.html)) you can place the text on top correctly.

I used code below (adapted from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40621402/709166) SO answer). It combines multiple columns one row after another (i.e. will get all your `numPatients6month` columns in the chart order)

```
vals = pd.concat([nocidffinal.numPatients6month, dffinal.numPatients6month], axis=1)
vals = vals.stack().reset_index(level=[0,1], drop=True)
```

[image]

This is my full code

```
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rcParams['axes.prop_cycle'] = ("cycler('color', 'rg')")
dffinal['CI-noCI']='Cognitive Impairement'
nocidffinal['CI-noCI']='Non Cognitive Impairement'
res=pd.concat([dffinal,nocidffinal])

# Copied to clipboard from SO question above
# Comment out if you already have your dataframes
nocidffinal = pd.read_clipboard().reset_index() 
dffinal = pd.read_clipboard().reset_index() 

# This will merge columns in order of the chart
vals = pd.concat([nocidffinal.numPatients6month, dffinal.numPatients6month], axis=1)
vals = vals.stack().reset_index(level=[0,1], drop=True)

# Plot the chart
ax = sns.barplot(x='6month', y='final-formula', data=res, hue='CI-noCI')
_ = plt.xticks(fontsize=8, rotation=45)

# Add the values on top of each correct bar
for idx, p in enumerate(ax.patches):
    height = p.get_height()
    ax.text(p.get_x()+p.get_width()/2.,
            height + height*.01,
            vals[idx],
            ha="center")
```

Comment: I hope you can help with me to launch the result as you did. I am getting error at nocidffinal = pd.read_clipboard().reset_index()

Comment: Cheers to the response<3 It now works perfectly. I wish I could give double  reward :). I am new beginner and firstly I did not realize I should delete this line: pd.read_clipboard().reset_index()  maybe its good to update your answer without having those two line for other new beginner like me :

Comment: Yes, glad it works. The `read_clipboard` is for dataframes `nocidffinal` and `dffinal` which I copied to my clipboard from above. For you, you already have these so you can comment those lines out out :)

Comment: yea I figured out how it works and what they are again thanks :)